# What is the difference between activity visible liftime and foreground lifetime?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

We know that the android activity cycle has multiple phases.

between `onStart()` and `onStop()` is called the visible lifetime
between `onResume()` and `onPause()` is called the foreground lifetime

What are the the key difference between them?  Please give examples if possible.

Answer (score 12):

If I display an Activity on the screen and the user is interacting with it, it is both in the foreground and visible.

If I start another Activity, which is transparent and shows a dialog box over the previous Activity, then the new Activity (the dialog box) is in the foreground and the old Activity is *not* in the foreground but still visible.

Comment: @Bader Still waiting for more answers?

Answer (score 3):

between `onStart()` and `onStop()` called visible lifetime that mean that the activity is visible either entire activity or partially visible  and the user can see it  on the screen and interacte with

between `onResume()` and `onPause()` called foreground lifetime that your activity is full visible and running and have full  focus .

**UPDATE**

partially visible for example if another activity come in front of the current one and it only display a dialog and a transparent background . the user can see that activity but cant interact with it

Comment: thanks, but what you mean in partially visible ? can you give me an exampple ?

Comment: partially visible for example if another activity come in front of the current one and it only display a dialog and a transparent background . the user can see that activity but cant interact with it

Answer (score 1):

**Foreground Activity**: You’d think what the user is currently interacting with would be the most important thing to keep alive.

**Visible Activity**: You’ll find that there are situations where your activity can be visible but not in the foreground. A simple example is when the foreground activity starts a new activity with Dialog theme or a translucent activity. Another example might when you invoke the runtime permission dialog.

Please find below link for better understanding

https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/who-lives-and-who-dies-process-priorities-on-android-cb151f39044f

Answer (score 0):

**The Visible Lifetime**: Although this is termed the "visible lifetime", the app may not be directly visible and interacting with the user at any one time if it is not in the foreground. The feature that distinguishes this lifetime is that, even if not in the foreground, the app maintains resources such that it can instantaneously return to the foreground.

**The Foreground Lifetime**: During foreground lifetime the activity is in front of all other activities and interacting with the user.